# Symfony 2 service container is null

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony 2 and trying to create some simple application to learn. I created a bundle `GoogleApiBundle`. Inside the bundle, I have a controller `YouTubeController`, which is a service:

```
//services.yml
service:
    myname_googleapi_youtube:
        class: Myname\GoogleApiBundle\Controller\YouTubeController
```

In another bundle, I try to call a function in `YouTubeController`

```
//anotherController.php
$service = $this->get('myname_googleapi_youtube');
$result = $service->getResultFunction();

//YouTubeController.php
public function getResultFunction()
{
    $parameter = $this->container->getParameter('a');
    //...
}
```

Then I get an exception `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getParameter() on a non-object ...`, because `$this->container` is `NULL`.

I searched but didn't get an answer. Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//services.yml
service:
    myname_googleapi_youtube:
        class: Myname\GoogleApiBundle\Controller\YouTubeController
        arguments: [@service_container]
```

And you would have:

```
<?php

namespace Myname\GoogleApiBundle\Controller

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class YouTubeController
{
    /**
    * @param ContainerInterface $container
    */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
    * Obtain some results
    */
    public function getResultFunction()
    {
        $parameter = $this->container->getParameter('a');
        //...
    }

    /**
    * Get a service from the container
    *
    * @param string The service to get
    */
    protected function get($service)
    {
        return $this->container->get($service);
    }
}
```

---

This practice is very controversial, so I'd recommend that you have a quick read at these:

- [Controllers as Services in Symfony2](http://ankitchauhan22.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/controllers-as-services-in-symfony2.html)
- [Do you want DIC with that Controller?](http://pooteeweet.org/blog/1947)
- [Symfony2: Make my Controllers Services?](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/controllers-services)

Comment: Thank you. I got exception `ServiceNotFoundException: The service "myname_googleapi_youtube" has a dependency on a non-existent service "session_container".`

Comment: This is really ugly from Symfony actually since the base Controller class implements ContainerAwareInterface. Anyway good answer!

Comment: if class impliment ContainerAwareInterfaceservices you need to set container :- 
        class: Myname\GoogleApiBundle\Controller\YouTubeController
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]