# Symfony2 How to use parameters.yml in a controller as a variable

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with a Symfony2 project.

I am trying to use a pice of data decleared in parameters.yml and use this data in one of my controllers.

I have read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html) in Symfony2 documentation about `getParameters()` but it does not work.

In my parameters.yml i have done this:

```
sitemap_root_url: http:/example.co.uk/news/
```

In my controller I am trying this:

```
$this->test = $this->container->getParameters('sitemap_root_url');
```

This is the error I get:

```
Notice: Undefined property $container
```

Comment: You could inject `@service_container` as described in [this thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21130535/741782

Answer (score 2):

Try `$this->container->getParameter('sitemap_root_url');`

It works well for me, I use Symfony 2.5.

If you want to use container in your controller you can extend

> Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
>   (Symfony base controller).

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/HelloController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you will be able to get your property.
Example Controller which works for me:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
            return new Response(
                    $this->container->getParameter('sitemap_root_url');
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this it does not work, it is crying about 'conteiner' part...pas how do I check the version of the Symfony2 I am running

Comment: composer.json file, then find "require" part and value in "symfony/symfony" will be your version of symfony.

Comment: Did you extend Symfony Controller or you controller is 'plain' class ?

Comment: My class already extends another class.....Can I Inject the container class in my __construct()..?

Comment: Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27378041/3133441 . If you created controller as same as in official tutorial you HAVE to has access to container. Show me your controller, paste it to pastebin.com if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66471/discussion-between-jakon-and-tomazi).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `$container` is not declared in your controller, if you want to access the controller you can extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` and then use `$this->container->getParameter('sitemap_root_url')`

Otherwise you'll have to declare your controller as a service and inject the container.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have to answer (i wanted to edit the first answer) but you have an unnecessary **s** in your `getParameters()`, that's all the problem i guess ;)

Comment: Why would misspelling a method name result in an undefined property: container error message?

Answer (score 0):

for symfony 2.6

```
$this->container->getParameter('api_key');
```

above symfony 2.6

```
$this->getParameter('api_key');
```