# Symfony: Call to a member function has() on null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I am beginner in Symfony & its already making me sick!

This is my simple code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Users;

class ValidationController extends Controller
{
    public function alreadyExists($email){
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Users');  //ERROR IN THIS LINE
        $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
        if($user==NULL) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}

?>
```

When I call the function `alreadyExists` it is giving me this error:

> Error: Call to a member function has() on null in
>   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php
>   (line 356)

Not sure but I think it is failing to get doctrine. When I trace, the error actually occurs in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php` file on line 356, ie:

```
protected function getDoctrine()
    {
        if (!$this->container->has('doctrine')) {  ///LINE NO. 356
            throw new \LogicException('The DoctrineBundle is not registered in your application.');
        }
        return $this->container->get('doctrine');
    }
```

The exact same function works well if I cut-paste it in another controller, even though its the same code and the other controller has exact same `namespace` & `use` statements.

Please someone let me know what is this error & why the heck is this happening?

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23200

Comment: Would say that $container is NULL. Look here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129590/symfony-2-service-container-is-null

Comment: @YaatSuka But in my case its not a service, its controller. Pardon my ignorance but how exactly symfony diffrentiates between controller & service?

Comment: I think its the same issue as @Wreigh pointed out, except the changes suggested in that link are not working for me...

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as your previous question.  The Symfony framework does some special processing for controllers and takes care of calling $controller->setContainer($container) before kicking off the controller action.  I assume you are new'ing the controller directly and of course not calling setContainer.  At this stage in the game you probably think that controllers should contain all your logic which is wrong thinking.  Try skimming through the container chapter to get a better understanding of services.

Comment: Here are a couple of "big picture" Symfony links that might help: http://symfony.com/doc/master/introduction/http_fundamentals.html http://symfony.com/doc/master/introduction/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html

Comment: Small clarification: a controller is meant to be called by SF itself (for the reasons explained by @Cerad), not by the developer. If not, services might be the way to go (in that case you can inject required dependencies like the EM quite easily).